# Append Data to an Existing File Without Replacing using Github REST API

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I'm trying to append data to a JSON file in a github repository using Github REST API calls. These rest calls are executed using Postman and for each Postman request, a new line should be added to the existing JSON file. However, I managed to retrieve the whole file content from the git repository (using `GET` request) and send a new `PUT` request with the updated file content.

Is there any way to update the existing file in the git repository without retrieving and updating it each time?. Even if I can use some sort of metadata file, that would be fine in my case.

References: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Man! Still looking for someone who's done this

Answer (score 0):

I've also been thinking about the same thing for storing basic analytics logs of web traffic in a CSV file.

Having done some research I think the best approach would simply be to generate a CSV over the course of a fixed time period/user session/VM instance and then upload each CSV individually to a repo.

This means no need to read previous files, can query files by date added etc and if you want to aggregate data you can write your own software to pull in multiple files and aggregate fairly straightforwardly.

Would this suit your use case too?